# Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE while running jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jar, datasource

As mentioned in the headline of question I am facing issue `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`. The application I have built is on spring boot and working fine when I run the code in intellij.

I have followed several questions regarding the same exception and they suggested that I need to add `spring.datasource` properties in my application.properties file. I already have them and still facing the same issue. This issue occurs when I create jar file using artifacts of intellij and then run it by the following command. 
`java - jar myJar.jar`

My application.properties file

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_wssmith?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = 
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Error Log while running jar

`ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).`

Comment: where is your `application.properties` file located ?

Comment: in the project in intellij it is in src/main/resources, 
in the jar when i open it using winrar its not in any folder its outside folders

Comment: ok. During the datasource bean creation, spring starts by reading the driver class name property. This exception is thrown when he can't manage to read the datasource properties. try to run it using `mvn spring-boot:run`, make sure you don't have another `application.properties` file under `config` folder (outside of your jar file) .Do you have any Datasource bean configured in your project ? . Can you post the content of your `pom.xml` (even if i don't think it may be the problem)

Comment: trying to run it with mvn spring boot command, i didnt understand the part of config folder... i dont have any such folder where my jar is replaced

Comment: you can also try removing the spaces before and after the sign `=` and fill the username and password properties. Maybe this is what is causing the issue... not convinced btw..

Comment: working with mvn spring boot command

Comment: i have the username and password set, just didnt show here for security purpose

Comment: if you build your jar using maven command instead of using intellij, the java -jar yourjar.jar works ? just to be sure that this is linked to intellij maven conf.

Comment: that worked, shouldnt have built jar using artifacts thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create the jar from maven, to do that go to **View** on top then **Tool Windows/Maven Projects** and from there double click on install in **LifeCycle** option in maven. Use the jar created by that command instead of using intellij. It
Should work.